# unbale to add filter for the email contains same value in rich text filter

Tags: filters, richtextarea, warning

I want to show warning message on lead when email address has same values ​​in more than one lead record. I'm trying to add a filter to the rich text filter criteria but I can't.[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Community!!!. Could you please help to edit your question and add more details? to understand your issue clearly and please add the image again due to it's not correctly added during your initial question submission.

Thanks.

Comment: @MohanrajSivalingam i have added the image again.

Comment: CONTAINS operator is not supported for long text or rich text fields

Comment: @cropredy is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Component visibility can't look at values other than on the existing record - yet you want to compare against other Lead records?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to set Component Visibility for a rich text component that if the current record's `Email` exists on another Lead.

*ignore my comment about CONTAINS as I misunderstood your intent*

Component Visibility can only consider the values in the current record (or current context like running user). Hence, to see if there is another Lead with same email won't work.

HOWEVER, SFDC Duplicate Rules could be used which would automatically surface potential duplicates and allow the user to take action